# MPI allocating massive amounts of memory on startup

Tags: fortran, mpi, intel-fortran, intel-mpi

I am trying to run an MPI application compiled with mpiifort (ifort (IFORT) 2021.6.0 20220226) using mpiexec.hydra (Intel(R) MPI Library for Linux* OS, Version 2021.6 Build 20220227 (id: 28877f3f32)), on a machine with 36 Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8360Y CPU @ 2.40GHz cores.

Before any actual work is done, that is before the actual application prints any output, massive amounts of memory are allocated (tens to hundreds of GB). This seems to depend on the number of cores used. With more than 30 cores, MPI actually crashes because it runs out of memory.

Is this an MPI or compiler bug? What is all this memory allocated for? Can I control its amount somehow?

Edit: here's a minimal example

```
program test
  implicit none 
  integer :: mpi_err

  include "mpif.h"

  call MPI_INIT(mpi_err)
  call MPI_FINALIZE()

end program
```

Comment: What kind of operating system? There is an official support forum on the Intel website.

Comment: It's Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Comment: Does it dot his for non-MPI executables like `echo $PWD`?

Comment: It doesn't. A bit of playing around reveals it happens in MPI_INIT

Comment: Check your `I_MPI` environment variables. Are you setting eager stuff?

Comment: Only I_MPI_ROOT is set